# Why is CLK_FLASH separate from CLK_CPU?

Tags: atmega328

The ATmega328P has a separate clock signal for Flash and EEPROM (CLK<sub>FLASH</sub>) than it has for the RAM (CLK<sub>CPU</sub>). Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to do with programming the chip. When you are programming the chip using an external programmer you need the flash and EEPROM to be running. However you don't want the CPU to be running since you are doing things with the flash that it would normally access. By having the CPU (and RAM) on a separate clock you can clock the flash without clocking the CPU and all is well.